# Reading Raw bytes from a C float array in Javascript (conversion to JS array)

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, floating-point, buffer

I'm transferring bytes over a network. These bytes originated as a C `float[]` array.

The bytes are being received by a node.js service, but I'm a bit stumped on the conversion from a Buffer to an array of the correct floats/doubles.

Some online resources offer some assistance but the numbers just don't come across corrently. Mostly they are either very long integers or long floating points.

Length of the float array is 32.

**Update**

As per request this is the node.js buffer when it arrives:

```
<Buffer 00 50 4f d7 06 70 77 bf ca 24 d7 bf 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 0b d7 23 3c 00 00 00 00 a6 9b c4 3c a4 70 3d 3f 0a d7 23 3c 
00 00 00 00 00 00 ... >
```

This is the buffer after `buf.toString()`

```
PO�pw��$׿
                   �#<���<�p=?
�#<�@
ף<ff�?
�#=�A
```

The output should look something like this:

```
output = [1.23, 4.56, -0.23, 0.02, 1.22, ...] <length=32>
```

**Update #2**

As per request here's some code for the sender/receiver.

Sender (C application):

```
float tmp[] = { var1, var2, var3, var4, ..., var32 }
byte * b = (byte *) &tmp;
Serial.write(b, 32 * sizeof(float));
```

Receiver (node.js):

```
// Using ByteLength parser @ 32 * 4 bytes length
parser.on('data', (data) => console.log(data))
```

Comment: This might need more info. You said "Mostly they are either very long integers or long floating points that end with e-41 or similar." - is that the resources or your numbers? Try an array with one number only and get that working. Do you know how big the floats are (in bytes)? I presume you mean it has 22 numbers?

Comment: What do the bytes look like when you view them in node.js..  A hex dump will do.

Comment: Rather than describe output, posting the true output and its expected value add clarity.

Comment: Is the `Float23` in the title a typo for `Float32`, or `Float22` (referring somehow to the size of the array) or something else?

Comment: This is too broad.  What protocol are you using to transfer the data?

Comment: updates added..

Comment: Also, it's over serial.

Comment: How about some actual *code*?

Comment: Didn't think it's relevant here, because just looking to do a byte to type conversion in javascript. However, i can post the sender and receiver code.

Comment: code added, shows sender/receiver snippets now

Comment: I have a feeling that correct parsing of the bytes will come down to whether the numbers are stored as little endian or big endian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was fairly simple but non-trivial.

First, I had to know what the byte data type incoming was. In this case it was a `float` type.

C `float` types allocate 4 bytes per address. Since I had an array of 32 floats (list size was 32), there were 4*32 byte locations to read from in the steam. All I had to do was iterate the buffer 4 positions at a time and read the next 4 bytes. Here's some sample code of how I did that:

```
var tmp = [];
for(var i =0; i < buf.length/4; i++) {
    tmp.push(buf.readFloatBE(i*4));
}
```

So tmp contains my float array. There was some experimentation required, and the Javascript Buffer object has 2 prototype methods to read floats:

- readFloatBE()
- readFloatLE()

BE and LE stand for "Big Endian" and "Little Endian". This denotes the ordering of the bytes for numbers, and varies from compiler to compiler. In this case I had to use BE to get it working.